# Get total value from grid column Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, rest

Can someone help me to solve this issue. I want to get the total value of the last column value. below is my HTML code.

```
  <div *ngFor="let order of orders |filter:searchText">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-text>
        {{order.OrderNo}}
      </ion-text>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-text>
        {{order.CustomerName}}
      </ion-text>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-text>
        {{order.PaymentType}}
      </ion-text>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-text>
        {{order.TotalPrice | currency:''}}
      </ion-text>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
<h6>Total value: </h6>
```

[image: My grid]

Comment: public total:any=;

this.total = this.orders.map(a => parseFloat(a.TotalPrice)).reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });

console.log(total);

Answer (score 0):

You can just use javascript in your template like:

```html
<h6>Total value: {{ orders.reduce((acc, nxt) => acc + nxt) | currency:'' }}</h6>
```

However, having logic in your template is generally bad practice. Create a function in your component and call it from your template:
example.component.ts

```js
// replace any with actual type
sum(orders: any[]): number {
   return orders.reduce((acc, nxt) => acc + nxt);
}
```

example.component.html

```html
<h6>Total value: {{ sum(orders) | currency:'' }}</h6>
```

Comment: It's not worked. Can u help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try using pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'total'
})
export class TotalPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any): any {
    let total = 0;
    array.forEach(element => {
        total += element.totalPrice;
        // you may need to modify total price if it contains any currency and convert it into int
    });

    return total;
 }
}
```

And use it into html file like

```
<h6>Total value: {{ orders | total }}</h6>
```